# combobox not displaying items

Tags: c#, string, combobox, dataset

Hi all I have problem with following:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in data.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string value = dr["name"].ToString();
    combobox.Items.Add(value);                
}
```

My values are getting to value variable but not getting into combobox list. 
Anything I can do?

Comment: where in page licecyle are you doing that?

Comment: Does the combobox have a datasource?  If so, you should update the datasource and not the combobox directly.  As is, the posted code doesn't show any problems.

Comment: So combobox should work this way? This is n-tier application. I am not allowed to use datasource, I am getting dataset from data layer. That's why I am using this type of coding. Problem is that when I start form I don't get anything to combobox. And I debug and see that it is reading data and putting it in..But no display from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add objects with properties of value and displayMember to the ComboBox.
You can create a Struct with those properties and then add instances of the struct to the combobox.

```
struct NewItem
{
    private string _displayMember;
    private string _value;
    public NewItem(string displayMember, string value)
    {
        _displayMember = displayMember;
        _value = value;
    }
    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _displayMember;
        }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add NewItem to the combobox:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in data.Tables[0].Rows)         
{             
    string value = dr["value"].ToString(); 
    string displayMember= dr["name"].ToString();            
    combobox.Items.Add(new NewItem(displayMember,value));                         
}
```

Comment: Of course the is no restriction for value and displaymember to be the same. I just usually use as the value the Id and as the displaymemeber the name.

Comment: this is still not displaying anything :)

Comment: so I have one windows form. where I call all class libraries. I get values back, but I can't display them

Comment: code is too big for this site...I have like 50 classes and so on... But right now I am using the above code..as you wrote..and still nothing

Comment: just put the code of the struct youc reated and the new implementation for filling the combobox...Its strange is not working caouse Im using that code in a project...

Comment: Your code is working perfectly..I have missed something while opening form...I had to put your code when form loads..and then it worked..thak you!